# Best way to allocate and deallocate a dynamic list in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dynamic-memory-allocation, tlist

I'm new to Delphi and trying to figure out how to deal with memory management.
I have a class, TFileData, that is dynamically allocated and put into a list. Every time I reload data from files I need to release the old objects and allocate new.

To allocate I use this function:

```
function TImportXmlForm.GetLanguageFileData: TList<TFileData>;
begin
  if FAllFiles = nil then
    FAllFiles := TList<TFileData>.Create;
  Result := FAllFiles;
end{function};
```

To deallocate:

```
if Assigned(FAllFiles) then
begin
  while FAllFiles.Count > 0 do
  begin
    FAllFiles.Items[0].Free;
    FAllFiles.Delete(0);
  end;
  FAllFiles.Free;
  FAllFiles := nil;
end{if};
```

What is the "best practice" for this kind of programming patterns?

Comment: depending on what is your file, i'd considered making `TFileData`  a `record` ,and then using `TList<TFileData>`, `TDictionary<...,TFileData>` or just `array of TFileData`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into the pros and cons of records eventually. For now I use classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `TObjectList<T>` instead of `TList<T>`.

By default `TObjectList<T>` will free the object when you delete it from the list or all objects when you free the objectlist itself. This is controlled by the `OwnsObjects` parameter of the constructor which is by default `True`.